# Is there a way to reduce multiple methods as one method with Function<? super T, ?> as methode parameter?

Tags: java, function, stream

I have several methods that are basically all the same except for one method that is called in these methods.

Example:

```java
protected List < DeadlineEntity > getEntityOneDeadlines() {
    return deadLineEntityList
        .stream()
        .filter(m - > getEntityOneDeadlineDbs().stream().anyMatch(p - > m.getDb_4() != null && m.getDb_4().equals(p)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

protected List < DeadlineEntity > getEntityTwoDeadlines() {
    return deadLineEntityList
        .stream()
        .filter(m - > getEntityTwoDeadlineDbs().stream().anyMatch(p - > m.getDb_5() != null && m.getDb_5().equals(p)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

So the only difference is the method `getDB()`.

Since I don't want to have this method 10 times, I thought of writing this into a method and then controlling it via the input parameters.

My attempt looks like this:

```java
protected List < DeadLineEntity > getDeadlines(List < Integer > deadLineDbList, Function << ? super T, ? > dbProperty) {
    return deadLineEntityList
        .stream()
        .filter(m - > deadLineDbList.stream().anyMatch(p - > ....))
}
```

In method `anymatch()` I do not get further.

This is how I would want to use it:

```
List<DeadlineEntity> list1 = getDeadlines(getEntityOneDeadlineDbs(), EntityOne::getDb_4());
List<DeadlineEntity> list2 = getDeadlines(getEntityTwoDeadlineDbs(), EntityTwo::getDb_5());
```

What do you think? is this a good approach?
What would be the further procedure in the `getDeadlines()` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `Supplier` to insert the required instance of the `List` and `Function` to substitute the getter from `DeadlineEntity` to `T` compliant with the `getEntityXXX` method generic type of the returned List:

```
protected <T> List<DeadlineEntity> getDeadlines(Supplier<List<T>> dbProperty, Function<DeadlineEntity, T> getter) {
    return deadLineEntityList
            .stream()
            .filter(m -> dbProperty.get()
                                   .stream()
                                   .anyMatch(p -> getter.apply(m) != null && 
                                                  getter.apply(m).equals(p)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

```
List<DeadlineEntity> one = getDeadlines(this::getEntityOneDeadlineDbs, DeadlineEntity::getDb_4);
List<DeadlineEntity> two = getDeadlines(this::getEntityTwoDeadlineDbs, DeadlineEntity::getDb_5);
```

Edit: To make the code a bit more readable, I'd filter out all `p` equal to `null` first and then simplify the lambda expression and switch the parameters of the `equals` call in the `anyMatch` method to be null-safe:

```
protected <T> List<DeadlineEntity> getDeadlines(Supplier<List<T>> dbProperty, Function<DeadlineEntity, T> getter) {
    return deadLineEntityList
            .stream()
            .filter(m -> dbProperty.get().stream()
                    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                    .anyMatch(p -> p.equals(getter.apply(m))))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `filter` Method takes a `Predicate` as a parameter. So you can split the predicate from the rest.

```
protected List<DeadlineEntity> getEntityDeadlines(Predicate filterPredicate) {
    return deadLineEntityList
            .stream()
            .filter(filterPredicate)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

protected List<DeadlineEntity> getEntityOneDeadlines() {
    return getEntityDeadlines(getDb4Filter());
}

protected List<DeadlineEntity> getEntityTwoDeadlines() {
    return getEntityDeadlines(getDb5Filter());
}

protected Predicate<DeadlineEntity> getDb4Filter() {
    return m -> getEntityOneDeadlineDbs().stream().anyMatch(p -> m.getDb_4() != null && m.getDb_4().equals(p));
}

protected Predicate<DeadlineEntity> getDb5Filter() {
    return m -> getEntityTwoDeadlineDbs().stream().anyMatch(p -> m.getDb_5() != null && m.getDb_5().equals(p));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it could be easyer to pass the return of getDB to your method ? (if it's always the same type).

If you need to send a function, it seams like you should use a `Supplier<T>` instead of the `Function<? super T, ?>` as getBD has no parameter.

To use it, you have to use the `get()` method of the Supplier class :

```
protected List<DeadLineEntity> getDeadlines(List<Integer> deadLineDbList, Supplier<T> dbProperty) {
    return deadLineEntityList
            .stream()
            .filter(m -> deadLineDbList.stream()
                         .anyMatch(p -> dbProperty.get() != null && dbProperty.get().equals(p)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```